# Count child members from parent value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like `conversations` and `conversation_timelines`

**conversations** table example

```
|  id   |   last_active   |   category_id   |
|-------------------------------------------|
|  1    |   1552462134    |        1        |
|  2    |   1552461332    |        1        |
|  3    |   1552462312    |        2        |
|  4    |   1552461772    |        1        |
```

**conversation_timelines** table example

```
|  id   |  conversation_id  |  message  |  created_time  |
|--------------------------------------------------------|
|  1    |        1          |  hi       |  1552462066    |
|  2    |        1          |  hello    |  1552462172    |
|  3    |        1          |  world    |  1552462188    |
|  4    |        2          |  another  |  1552462141    |
```

What I want to query is **Counting the number of records in** `conversation_timelines` **that has** `created_time > conversation's last_active` **WHERE conversations.category_id = 1**

and the result world be like

```
|  conversation_id  |  count  |
|         1         |    2    |
|         2         |    1    |
```

Comment: I did edit, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following solution, using a `JOIN` with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT c.id AS `conversation_id`, COUNT(ct.id) AS `count`
FROM conversation c INNER JOIN conversation_timelines ct ON c.id = ct.conversation_id 
WHERE ct.created_time > c.last_active AND c.category_id = 1
GROUP BY c.id
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=39ad9e5ceb3d8161bad47bced8a0008e)

Answer (score 4):

use `join` and `group by` like below

```
  SELECT ct.conversation_id,count(ct.message)
  FROM conversation_timelines ct
  INNER JOIN  conversation c on c.id=ct.conversation_id and c.category_id=1
  and ct.created_time>c.last_active
  GROUP BY ct.conversation_id
```